# How to select first child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

How do I select the first div in these divs (the one with `id=div1`) using first child selectors?

```
<div class="alldivs">
   <div class="onediv" id="div1"> 1 This one </div>
   <div class="onediv" id="div2"> 2 </div>
   <div class="onediv" id="div3"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In plain **JavaScript** you would use something like:

```js
// Single
document.querySelector(".onediv").classList.add("red"); 

// Multiple (deeply nested)
document.querySelectorAll(".onediv:first-child").forEach(EL => EL.classList.add("red"));
```

Or by Parent Element using [Element.firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild):

```js
// Single Parent 
document.querySelector(".alldivs").firstElementChild.classList.add("red");

// Multiple parents
document.querySelector(".alldivs").forEach(EL => EL.firstElementChild.classList.add("red"));
```

### jQuery get first child

Use: `$(".onediv").eq(0)`

Other examples of *selectors* and *methods* targeting the **first** `LI` inside an `UL`:

| Syntax | Type | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) | Method | `$("li").eq(0)` |
| [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) | Method | `$("li").first()` |
| [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) | Selector | `$("li:eq(0)")` |
| [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) | Selector | `$("li:first")` |
| [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) | Selector | `$("li:first-child")` |
| [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) | Selector | `$("li:lt(1)")` |
| [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) | Selector | `$("li:nth-child(1)")` |
| [.slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) | Method | `$("li").slice(0,1)` |

There are some slight differences in how they operate regarding depth. Play with the below demo examples:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  $("li").removeClass("red");
  new Function(`return (${this.value})`)();
}).trigger("change");
```

```css
.red {color: red;}
option[disabled] {font-size: 1.4em; color: blue;}
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled>jQuery examples:</option>

  <option>$("li").eq(0).addClass("red")</option>
  <option>$("li:eq(0)").addClass("red")</option>
  <option>$("li").first().addClass("red")</option>
  <option>$("li:first").addClass("red")</option>
  <option>$("li:first-child").addClass("red")</option>
  <option>$("li:lt(1)").addClass("red")</option>
  <option>$("li:nth-child(1)").addClass("red")</option>
  <option>$("li").slice(0,1).addClass("red")</option>

  <option disabled>JavaScript examples:</option>

  <option>document.querySelector("li").classList.add("red")</option>
  <option>document.querySelectorAll("li:first-child").forEach(EL => EL.classList.add("red"))</option>

  <option disabled>Mixed jQuery + JavaScript</option>

  <option>$("li")[0].classList.add("red")</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2
    <ul>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
```

you can also use `[i]` to get the JS Element by *index* out of the jQuery elements collection like eg:

```js
$("li")[0]
```

but now that you have the native JS `Element` representation you have to use JavaScript methods eg:

```js
$("li")[0].classList.add("active"); // Adds class "active" to the first LI in the DOM
```

or you *can* (**don't - it's bad design**) wrap it back into a jQuery object

```js
$( $("li")[0] ).addClass("active"); // Don't! Use .eq() instead
```

Answer (score 22):

```
$('div.alldivs :first-child');
```

Or you can just refer to the id directly:

```
$('#div1');
```

As suggested, you might be better of using the child selector:

```
$('div.alldivs > div:first-child')
```

If you dont **have** to use `first-child`, you could use `:first` as also suggested, or  `$('div.alldivs').children(0)`.

Comment: You need a space in your first one. Otherwise it'll just match the instance (if any) of `div.alldivs` that is a first child.

Comment: This will return every first child of any descendant, not only the first div here.

Comment: $('div.alldivs > div:first-child');

Comment: @kennis: That won't work. That will match any div that happens to be the first child. You really want `div:first-of-type`, but that's apparently not supported in jQuery. (Should have seen that one earlier, but missed it in the question.)

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector.

In your example...

```
$('div.alldivs div:first-child')
```

This will also match any first child descendents that meet the selection criteria.

> While `:first` matches only a single element, the `:first-child` selector can match more than one: one for each parent. This is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)`.

For the first matched *only*, use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector.

Alternatively, [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) suggested using the [*direct descendent selector*](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to get only direct children...

```
$('div.alldivs > div:first-child')
```

Comment: It might be better to use the child selector here `>`. Or maybe just: `$('div.alldivs').children().first();` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

if you have to find what first child text then this is the easiest solution for you

```
  $(".openReceipt").on("click", function() {
        console.log($(this).eq(0).find(".test").text());
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi we can use default method "first" in jQuery

Here some examples:

When you want to add class for first div

```
  $('.alldivs div').first().addClass('active');
```

When you want to change the remove the "onediv" class and add only to first child

```
   $('.alldivs div').removeClass('onediv').first().addClass('onediv');
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Roko mentioned you can do this in multiple ways.

1.Using the [jQuery first-child selector - SnoopCode](http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-first-child-selector)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".alldivs onediv:first-child").css("background-color","yellow");
        }
```

2. Using [jQuery eq Selector - SnoopCode](http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-eq-selector)

   ```
    $( "body" ).find( "onediv" ).eq(1).addClass( "red" );
   ```
3. Using [jQuery Id Selector - SnoopCode](http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-id-selector)

   ```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#div1").css("background-color: red;");
      });
   ```