# Applying hide to first element in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply an effect to the first element in an array but I recieve this error:

`$(...)[0].hide is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
var contain = $('.commentFormContainer');
(contain.length >= 2 ) ? contain[0].hide();
```

Comment: You could use `.first()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852452/how-to-select-first-child-with-jquery/5852609#5852609

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery object. You can not use indexer as it will give you DOM object and you can not call hide on it.

```
contain.eq(0).hide();
```

Or you can use [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) in selector.

```
$('.commentFormContainer:eq(0)').hide();
```

> Note that since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these
>   selectors reflect that fact. This is why $('.myclass:eq(1)') selects
>   the second element in the document with the class myclass, rather than
>   the first. In contrast, :nth-child(n) uses 1-based indexing to conform
>   to the CSS specification, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

Comment: `Or you can use :eq in selector, it would be more efficient` - how is that true? You've clearly read the docs, knowing that it's a jQuery extension, not a regular CSS selector. That means there's no improvement in using the `":eq()"` selector instead of `.eq()`, because jQuery has to get all elements, then filter manually in both situations. I would think using the selector is less efficient because jQuery has to parse the string and do more, while `.eq()` is straightforward and easier for jQuery.