# How to Access First Child Div of the Parent Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

On a click event for a div, I'm trying to assign a variable the text value of the first child of that divs parent div. For example, the html is something like this:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="firstChild">
        1234
    </div>

    <div class="secondChild">
        Hello
    </div>

    <div class="thridChild">
        Bye
    </div>

</div>
```

So I want it to assign a variable the text value of the firstChild div whenever the click on anything inside the parent div. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852452/how-to-select-first-child-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var text = $('.parentDiv:nth-child(1)').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of child `>` and `:first` selectors. Like this:

```
var divValue = $(".parentDiv>div:first").text();
```

This will select the first child div element and retrieve it's text value.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/wkowkdmd/)

Of course, if you have a class for it anyway you can just use `$(".firstChild").text();` but I assume that was just to help explain the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('.parentDiv div').click(function(){
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.parentDiv');
    //Do whatever you want with $parent
  });
});
```

Use jQuery [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to find the parent (the `.closest` bit)

Answer (score 0):

`.parentDiv:first-child` or
`.parentDiv:first` or
`.parentDiv:nth-child(1)` or even 
`.firstChild:first-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

You won't want to use a second selector, as that makes for slow performance.
Instead, search within your current element with `.find()`

```
var text = 'new text';
$('.parentDiv').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('div:first').html(text);
});
```