# how to find first level child of li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find first level children of a `li`.

For example, first level children of `Li` with `id='2'` = `E` , `F` .

```
<ul class="treeView">
    <li id="1">
        <span>A</span>
        <ul>
            <li id="2"><span>B</span>
                <ul>
                    <li id="5"><span>E</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="7"><span>G</span></li>
                            <li id="8"><span>H</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="6"><span>F</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="3"><span>C</span></li>
            <li id="4"><span>D</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I do

```
$('.treeView').find('#2 ul li span').each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

but it alert `E , G , H , F`.

How can I do this in jQuery?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select first child with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852452/how-to-select-first-child-with-jquery)

Comment: @lucky_starss Not the answer because that reference is for one childe element one step down. He wants multiple children that are one step down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.treeView').find('#2>ul>li>span').each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

`>` is the [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), allowing you to select only between the direct children of the current element.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$('#2 > ul > li > span')
```

This will select all the direct children `ul` of the `#2` and it's direct children `li`

```js
$('#2 > ul > li > span').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="treeView">
  <li id="1">
    <span>A</span>
    <ul>
      <li id="2"><span>B</span>
        <ul>
          <li id="5"><span>E</span>
            <ul>
              <li id="7"><span>G</span>
              </li>
              <li id="8"><span>H</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="6"><span>F</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="3"><span>C</span>
      </li>
      <li id="4"><span>D</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at below code snippet:

```js
$('.treeView').find('#2 > ul > li > span').each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="treeView">
    <li id="1">
        <span>A</span>
        <ul>
            <li id="2"><span>B</span>
                <ul>
                    <li id="5"><span>E</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="7"><span>G</span></li>
                            <li id="8"><span>H</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="6"><span>F</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="3"><span>C</span></li>
            <li id="4"><span>D</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one level down and all the children on that level use `.children()` you were so close... https://api.jquery.com/children/
`.children()` is meant to replace `.find()` in this instance.

`$('#2>ul').children().each(function () { alert($(this).text()); });`

Comment: $('#2').children('ul').children('li').children('span').css('color','red');

Comment: `$('#2>ul').children()`